# Android spinner divider not working

Tags: android, android-spinner, divider

I have an spinner with white background. Now i want to set divider between the spinner items but its not working.

I have done this so far.

In spinner.xml under layout

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    style="@style/spinner_style"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/height"
    android:layout_weight="1.5" 
    android:gravity="center"
    />
```

In styles.xml

```
<style name="applicationTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/spinner_style</item>
</style>

<style name="spinner_style" parent="android:Widget.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/gradient_spinner</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">2dp</item>
</style>
```

gradient_spinner.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item><layer-list>
        <item><shape>
                <gradient android:angle="90" android:endColor="#FFFFFF" android:startColor="#FFFFFF" android:type="linear" />

                <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000000" />

                <corners android:radius="4dp" />

                <padding android:bottom="3dp" android:left="3dp" android:right="3dp" android:top="3dp" />
            </shape></item>
        <item><bitmap android:gravity="right" android:src="@drawable/spinner_arrow" />
        </item>         
    </layer-list></item>
</selector>
```

It's working perfectly except the divider.
What's wrong with my code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what you want to do??? change Background or change Divider color??? becoz as you did `<item name="android:background">@drawable/gradient_spinner</item>`

Comment: gradient_spinner is for the curved spinner box and dropdown image. Now i just want to set the black divider which is not working.

Comment: Your code is working fine with me. check the Theme properly